# Selecting all possible combinations of variables

Tags: r, combinations, correlation

I have a dataset in which we measured well-being with 18 items and political orientation (let's just assume for the moment that political orientation is measured with one item).

A person’s well-being score can be computed by taking the average of all 18 items, but also of taking the average of each possible combination of items (e.g., all combination of one item, two items etc), resulting in `sum(choose(18, 0:18)) = 262,144` possible combinations.

I am interested in how the correlation coefficient between well-being and political orientation changes depending on how well-being is computed. That is, I am interested in getting all 18 (choose(18,1) = 18) correlation coefficients if well-being is assessed with each of the 18 items and then correlated with political orientation, all 153 correlation coefficients if well-being is computed with all possible combinations of 2-items and then correlated with political orientation etc. So in the end I'd be looking for 262,144 correlation coefficients.

The dataset looks something like this (just with >10,000 participants), whereas v19 is political orientation, v1 to v18 the well-being items.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(190), ncol = 19))
```

In essence, I am asking on how to compute the average of all combinations of 2 items, 3, … , 17 well-being items. I came across the `expand()` function of `tidyr`, but this seems to be doing something else.

Comment: You mention both "well-being score" and "political orientation", and earlier you mentioned 18 items, yet your sample data is 10 rows and 19 columns, unlabeled. Please explain how we're supposed to project your `rnorm` data with your description of your correlation dilemma.

Comment: Each column represents an item. Columns 1-18 (i.e., v1 to v18) represent the 18 well-being items, column 19 political orientation (v19). Each row stands for the responses of one participant. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some steps to (1) calculate the average across the combinations of 18 factors; and then (2) correlate each of those combined-averages with the 19th column (political orientation).

```r
set.seed(42)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(190), ncol = 19))
df[,1:3]
#          V1      V2      V3
# 1   1.37096  1.3049 -0.3066
# 2  -0.56470  2.2866 -1.7813
# 3   0.36313 -1.3889 -0.1719
# 4   0.63286 -0.2788  1.2147
# 5   0.40427 -0.1333  1.8952
# 6  -0.10612  0.6360 -0.4305
# 7   1.51152 -0.2843 -0.2573
# 8  -0.09466 -2.6565 -1.7632
# 9   2.01842 -2.4405  0.4601
# 10 -0.06271  1.3201 -0.6400
rowMeans(df[,c(1,2)])
#  [1]  1.3379  0.8610 -0.5129  0.1770  0.1355  0.2649  0.6136 -1.3756 -0.2110  0.6287
rowMeans(df[,c(1,3)])
#  [1]  0.53216 -1.17300  0.09561  0.92377  1.14973 -0.26830  0.62713 -0.92891  1.23926 -0.35135
rowMeans(df[,c(2,3)])
#  [1]  0.4991  0.2527 -0.7804  0.4679  0.8809  0.1027 -0.2708 -2.2098 -0.9902  0.3401
```

I show the row-means for three combinations because I want to verify where in the next step those values are found.

```r
means <- lapply(1:3, function(N) {
  do.call(cbind,
          lapply(asplit(combn(18, N), 2),
                 function(ind) rowMeans(df[, ind, drop = FALSE])))
})
str(means)
# List of 3
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:18] 1.371 -0.565 0.363 0.633 0.404 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:153] 1.338 0.861 -0.513 0.177 0.135 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:816] 0.7897 -0.0198 -0.3992 0.5229 0.722 ...
```

That last step produces a `means` object that contains the "1" (singular columns), "2" (pairwise row-averages), and "3"-deep combination-averages. Note that `choose(18,2)` is 153 (number of columns in `means[[2]]`) and `choose(18,3)` is 816 (`means[[3]]`). Each column represents the average of the respective columns combined.

I included `1` here (`choose(18,1)`) simply to keep all data in the same structure, since we do want to test correlation of the single-columns; other methods could be done to achieve this, I leaned towards consistency and simplicity.

To verify we have what we think, I'll pull out three columns from `means[[2]]` which correspond to the three `rowMeans` calculations I showed above based on direct access to `df` (inspection will reveal they are a match):

```r
means[[2]][,c(1,2,18)]
#          [,1]     [,2]    [,3]
#  [1,]  1.3379  0.53216  0.4991
#  [2,]  0.8610 -1.17300  0.2527
#  [3,] -0.5129  0.09561 -0.7804
#  [4,]  0.1770  0.92377  0.4679
#  [5,]  0.1355  1.14973  0.8809
#  [6,]  0.2649 -0.26830  0.1027
#  [7,]  0.6136  0.62713 -0.2708
#  [8,] -1.3756 -0.92891 -2.2098
#  [9,] -0.2110  1.23926 -0.9902
# [10,]  0.6287 -0.35135  0.3401
```

This means that the columns are ordered as `1,2`, `1,3`, `1,4`, ..., `1,18`, then `2,3` (column 18), `2,4`, etc, through `17,18` (column 153).

From here, correlating each of those columns with `V19` is not difficult:

```r
cors <- lapply(means, function(mn) apply(mn, 2, cor, df$V19))
str(cors)
# List of 3
#  $ : num [1:18] 0.2819 -0.3977 0.0426 0.2501 -0.063 ...
#  $ : num [1:153] -0.27 0.168 0.472 0.192 0.6 ...
#  $ : num [1:816] -0.1831 -0.063 -0.3355 0.0358 -0.3829 ...
cor(df$V1, df$V19)
# [1] 0.2819
cor(rowMeans(df[,c(1,2)]), df$V19)
# [1] -0.2702
cor(rowMeans(df[,c(1,3)]), df$V19)
# [1] 0.1677
cor(rowMeans(df[,c(1,2,3)]), df$V19)
# [1] -0.1831
cor(rowMeans(df[,c(1,2,4)]), df$V19)
# [1] -0.06303
```

---

Because of the way that was done, it should be straight-forward to change the `N` of 3 to whatever you may need ... realizing that `choose(18,9)` is 48620, generating those combination-averages is not instantaneous but still quite manageable:

```r
system.time({
  means18 <- lapply(1:18, function(N) {
    do.call(cbind,
            lapply(asplit(combn(18, N), 2),
                   function(ind) rowMeans(df[, ind, drop = FALSE])))
  })
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   41.65    0.58   50.35 
str(means18)
# List of 18
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:18] 1.371 -0.565 0.363 0.633 0.404 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:153] 1.338 0.861 -0.513 0.177 0.135 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:816] 0.7897 -0.0198 -0.3992 0.5229 0.722 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:3060] 0.7062 0.1614 -0.0406 0.24 0.6678 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:8568] 0.6061 0.0569 0.1191 0.0466 0.2606 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:18564] 0.5588 -0.0832 0.3619 0.146 0.2321 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:31824] 0.4265 -0.0449 0.3933 0.3251 0.095 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:43758] 0.2428 -0.0505 0.4221 0.1653 0.0153 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:48620] 0.3839 -0.0163 0.385 0.1335 -0.1191 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:43758] 0.4847 -0.0623 0.4115 0.2592 -0.2183 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:31824] 0.5498 0.0384 0.2829 0.4037 -0.259 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:18564] 0.5019 0.0442 0.2189 0.3281 -0.3759 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:8568] 0.3484 -0.0723 0.2117 0.2262 -0.3471 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:3060] 0.364 -0.102 0.197 0.29 -0.219 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:816] 0.334 -0.155 0.154 0.269 -0.232 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:153] 0.311 -0.242 0.217 0.235 -0.247 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:18] 0.282 -0.291 0.214 0.2 -0.198 ...
#  $ : num [1:10, 1] 0.254 -0.228 0.105 0.283 -0.139 ...
```

and the rest of the process can be completed in a similar manner.

Comment: Thank you, your code with the simulated data does exactly what I wanted. There were some issues adapting it to the actual data hence my long silence, but it now seems to be working.
Cheers!